# How to add a loop content to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

In my current project, I need to add a loop contents to an array where I can use it later. This is my code. I tried some way but they're not working. Can anybody give a help to fix it:

```
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++) {
    $pid = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
    $q = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
    $pname = get_product_name($pid);

    if($q == 0) { 
        continue;
    } else {
        $j = $i+1;
    }
```

I need to add the `$pid` to an array where I should be able to use `implode(",", $pid)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pids=array();
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
  $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
  $pids[]=$pid;
  $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
  $pname=get_product_name($pid);
  if($q==0){ 
    continue;
  }else{
    $j = $i+1;
  }
}
echo implode(' - ',$pids);
```

You should be a little more clear about what your end result should be, I could be a bit more specific

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, your method is working, that's what I really looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you just mean this?

```
$pids = array();
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
{
    $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
    $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
    if($q==0)
    { 
        continue;
    }
    // optimization... don't do anything if quantity is 0.
    $pids[] = $pid;
    $pname=get_product_name($pid);
}
echo implode(',', $pids);
```

Answer (score 0):

initialiaze $pid as an array first

```
$pid = array();
```

Now in your loop add the values to it

```
$pid[] =$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
```

note the square brackets with pid

after your loop you can extract the values from $pid

```
$someValue = $pid[0] * something';
```

I hope this is what u are looking for

Comment: actually I need an output like $id = 10,12,13

I tried yours mate, but its not what I wanted

Comment: you simply have to implode the $pid variable, i gave you a generic answer so you can understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

```
$pids = array();

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $cart)
{
 $pids[] = $cart['productid'];
}
```

This will get you a $pids array.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you initialize an array for your pids

`$arr_pids = array()`

and each time you want to add a pid to this array just use

`array_push($arr_pids, $pid)`